# REACT / TS - Render new DOM Element from array ends up in error Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my app you should be able to enter some search term, which then should be added to a list of already entered search terms. When you click on one of that entered search terms, the given search result should be shown on the page.

```
public render() {
     const  {error, isLoaded, items} = this.state; 
     const header = (<div><header className="App-header">
     <input type="text" id="tbx_Search" placeholder="Search..." /> 
     <button type="submit" className="fa fa-search searchButton" onClick={this.process} />
   </header>
   <p className="leftList">
       <LeftList terms={this.state.searchterms} />
</p></div>);
[...some API Stuff...] 
}
```

`this.state.searchterms` is an array of any.

```
private process(lList){
  // Get the searchterm as inputValue from Searchfield
const inputValue = (document.getElementById("tbx_Search") as HTMLInputElement).value;
// Call the API
this.getGifs(inputValue);

// create new dom nodes for a and li
const li = document.createElement("li");
const a = document.createElement("a");
// a.href = {this.getGifs(inputValue)};
a.innerText = inputValue;
li.appendChild(a);
// Add dom node to LeftList
 this.state.searchterms.push(li);

}
```

When I now call the process method, I get the following **error**:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLLIElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in ul (created by LeftList)
    in div (created by LeftList)
    in LeftList (created by App)
    in p (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
```

This is the render method of `LeftList`

```
 public render(){
    return(
        <div>
    <ul id="ul_LeftList">
        {this.props.terms}
    </ul>
    </div>
    )
}
```

My question is: Is there some easy way to show the `searchterms` in the list as intended? These `searchterms` should be in an `<a>` tag for further development.

Comment: It's not very clear at all what you're asking. The first code block is hard to read and seems unrelated to the question, the second directly modifies `this.state.searchterms` (which is a big React no-no), and your third uses the seemingly-unrelated `this.props.terms`. How do all these join up?

Comment: Having said that, `document.createElement` is a red flag. You don't provide raw DOM elements to `render`; you use React (via JSX or via `React.createElement`).

Comment: Okay, try to make it a little bit clearer: When I click the searchButton, de currently entered searchterm should be send to an API and also be pushed to the array of this.state.searchterms. This is for reloading the DOM of LeftList instantly when a new search term was entered. this.state.searchterms will be given to LinkList via the props of LinkList in the first code segment. Since I'm new to React, I really don't know if everything I did is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You DO NOT need to create elements like **li** and **a**. Instead just add all the searchterms to an array, pass that array as a prop to the LeftList component and change your render method to this:

```
    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <ul id="ul_LeftList">
            {this.props.terms.map((term) => (
              <li><a> {term} </a></li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create HTML elements like

```
private process(lList){
  // Get the searchterm as inputValue from Searchfield

    const inputValue = (document.getElementById("tbx_Search") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    // Call the API
    this.getGifs(inputValue);

    // create new dom nodes for a and li
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    // a.href = {this.getGifs(inputValue)};
    a.innerText = inputValue;
    li.appendChild(a);
    // Add dom node to LeftList
    this.state.searchterms.push(li);
}
```

Its understood by DOM, but not React. React expects element to be a DOM element which React then parses to create DOM elements itself using `React.createElement`, Also in order to update state you should use `setState`

```
 private process(lList){
      // Get the searchterm as inputValue from Searchfield
     const inputValue = (document.getElementById("tbx_Search") as HTMLInputElement).value;
     this.getGifs(inputValue);
     const element = <li><a href={inputValue}>{inputValue}</a></li>;
     this.setState(prevState => ({searchterms: [...prevState.searchterms, element]}))   
 }
```